# Pandas determine intersection point from two dataframes of different shape

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe containing all values for each pixel in an image. Is there a way to use the x and y coordinate of a pixels location in the image to determine its index value?

```
Xcord = 4
Ycord = 8

PandasIndexVal = Xcord*(NumberofCol)+ Ycord #or something like that.
```

Another way I am trying to think of it as is thatch I have a 2d array (x by y) representing an image and I have another that is a flattened version 
of the same matrices and I need to find the two index values that line up.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way. For all pixel values in row 1 of an image, are they in the same row or column or a pandas df? say pixel coordinates for row1 of image would be [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0) (3,0)]. Would thos be stored in the same row or column of a df? It would help if you could provide us an example of the df as well.

Comment: The index calculation you show is almost correct. Write it out on paper and you can probably get it right, but there's also not enough information to answer right now (not clear whether your linearized indices are column first or row first). Also, you can use [`np.ravel_multi_index()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html)